# I like to do multiple file upload using codeigniter along with drag and drop identical togmail upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'd like to do multiple file upload using codeigniter along with drag and drop like Gmail upload. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use dropzone to do drag & drop for Frontend
[dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

for Backend you can use any framework you need

for Codeigniter use this link [How to implement Dropzone in Codeigniter](https://arjunphp.com/drag-drop-file-upload-dropzone-js-codeigniter/)

Comment: Thanks for the great Hint AId Developer H. But i like to upload it database and should retrieve it desc order where i can use for shopping cart image view

Comment: check last 2 lines for inserting in database.
If you have a complex business logic you have to create model to do that
`public function upload() {
  if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
  $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
  // if you want to save in db,where here
  // with out model just for example
   $this->load->database(); // load database
   $this->db->insert('file_table',array('file_name' => $fileName));
  }`